# How to print Radio Control information

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I am using `mechanize` module to retrieve information from a web page. It has a radio control section which I select before moving to the next page. I could easily select the value by assigning value to it. But coulnt retrieve the value of the candidate radio button. `RadioSelect` part of my form looks like below:

```
<RadioControl(rdoSelect=[1634,ABX EXPRESS, 16650,XYZ EXP])>
```

I could easily set the values by:

```
br.form['txtSource']='1634,ABX EXPRESS'
```

What I want is to retireve the list :

```
[1634,ABX EXPRESS, 16650,XYZ EXP]
```

**UPDATE:**

When I gave

```
print br.form['rdoSelect']
```

It gives [] as result

I could get the value using

```
print br.form.possible_items("rdoSelect")
```

But its giving me this

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/ClientForm.py:2984: DeprecationWarning: [item.name for item in self.items]
  return c.possible_items(by_label)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
print br.form.possible_items("rdoSelect")
```

mechanize says to use:

```
options = [item.name for item in form.find_control('rdoSelect').items]
```

Example use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
r = br.open("http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_RADIO.html")
form = mechanize.ParseResponse(r, backwards_compat=False)[2]
options = [item.name for item in form.find_control('pizzasize').items]
print options
```

Yields:

```
['S', 'M', 'L']
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a deprecation warning is not an error. Usually it means the library or code you are running was written for an earlier version of Python.

I am not sure how txtSource relates to rdoSelect (seems you expect them to contain the same value?). However a radio button usually has a symbolic value rather than the text displayed. Can you provide a sample of the HTML code?